# How to Bake Material Output to Images In Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, unity, normal-map, roughness

I have created a procedural brick material in cycles that I would like to use in Unity. When I try baking the image, it seems to bake the normal, roughness and color into a single image when I would like them all separate. Does anyone know how to bake a material from cycles into different maps? Or bring a cycles material into Unity? Any help would be very much appreciated! I've attached a picture of my node setup:
[image: BrickNodeSetup]

Comment: I'm looking at the picture and am not 100% sure what is going wrong, but this is what is required:

Create a new image from the Image view (looks like you have that open in the lower-left) and give it a name and desired dimensions. Call it "Normal" so you don't confuse it with another file.

To be sure that things are going right, create a new material and stick a Texture node inside it ANYWHERE. Select the image you just created for that node. Apply that material to the model.

Then bake the normals. MAKE SURE YOU SAVE THE IMAGE THAT GETS OVERWRITTEN IN THE IMAGE VIEW!

Comment: What's confusing about your image is that it looks like you created a new texture node in the material containing an image called "Diffuse", which is already being used in another material (see the "2" in the node), and you are baking the Normals, not Diffuse. You may risk overwriting an existing texture if you bake the normals to that image and save it (assuming you are already using it somewhere else). Should work if you just generate a new image with a new name and put it in that texture node

Comment: I tried to bake the normals and diffuse on different images, but when I try baking the normals it just gives me an image with a flat purple color instead of the one generated by the nodes. Is there something I'm missing there? Thanks for the help though!